# Word wrap in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing an IF-THEN-ELSE statement with 19 OR statements contained within it. Is there a way to use word wrap to make it easier to see what I'm coding? Or is there some way to make this more doable? It's very difficult to keep track of all of the statements.

**Note:** I am not trying to use the Wrapandfit() function or any other function to modify cells, I am talking about the VBA window itself.

An example of the statement:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "Administration") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "Administrative") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "Administrator") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "Assistant") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "Coordinator") > 0 Then
Cells(i, 2).Value = "Administrative"
```

This matters partly because I can't just make everything on a separate line and delete the line breaks later because of the debugger (which also takes extra work to disable).

Comment: have you looked in to use the Case structure?  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the line continuation character `_`:

```
Function SmallPrime(n As Integer) As Boolean
    If n = 2 Or n = 3 Or n = 5 Or n = 7 _
       Or n = 11 Or n = 13 Or n = 17 _
       Or n = 19 Then
        SmallPrime = True
    Else
        SmallPrime = False
    End If
End Function
```

Note the space before the `_`

On edit:

If you want genuine word wrap on the editor level, you can keep an open copy of [TextPad](http://textpad.com/index.html) with wordwrap enabled and the VBA syntax highlighting definitions available from their website and then copy-paste into the VBA editor. (Notepad++ probably has similar functionality, though Textpad is what I am familiar with).

Comment: For OP's info: There is a limit to the number of times you can use the line continuation character for a single line. I think it is 25.

Comment: @ChipsLetten That is useful knowledge. I've never run into that restriction (I don't think I've ever used it more than 4 or 5 times in a row).

Comment: I think I was building a very long string. Really, really not recommended for a line of code!

Comment: For some reason it took me until now to understand what you were saying, but this is really helpful, thanks! It's exactly what I'm looking for. And 25 is much more than I need, as a few of those `Or` statements can fit on one line. I'm only trying to make everything fit into the window for VBA so this is totally sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "_" character

```
IF this
 OR this _ 
 OR this _
 OR this _
 THEN this
```

Comment: Would this work for multiple conditions? I'm not trying to have multiple Then statements, I'm using multiple If statements/conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think the answer is Yes.

Comment: So for example: `If this OR this OR this OR this THEN this`

Comment: I updated to my example code to show what it would like for your request.  Hopefully this helps and it's not too late!

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a separate function and put your 19 OR statements within the function. If you give the function a meaningful name, then your IF statement will become much clearer. (Unless you've got a massively long list of parameters for the function).

Here is an example:

```
Sub mainCode()

Dim i As Integer

    i = 3

    If theValueIsOk(i) Then
        ' do something
    Else
        ' do something else
    End If

End Sub

Private Function theValueIsOk(theValue As Integer) As Boolean

Dim result As Boolean

    result = False

    If theValue = 0 Then
        result = True
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

    If (theValue = 1) Or (theValue = 3) Then
        result = True
        GoTo Exit_Function
    End If

Exit_Function:
    theValueIsOk = result
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: So are you talking about making a User-Defined Function?

Comment: Not a UDF as such. You wouldn't call it from Excel but from VBA. I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make a particular argument take multiple values? I've used R for programming before and it will allow that when defining functions. That would be ideal since in this case I want to have 19 different conditions for the IF statement.

Comment: Fixed number or variable? For the latter, look up `ParamArray`. Also look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Neither, they're strings. The code I provided in the original post is a good example of what I'm trying to do, there would just be a total of 19 Instr() functions with different strings that it's searching for.

Comment: I meant a fixed number of parameters or a variable number.

Comment: Ah okay, a variable number. So if I were to put in either 10 or 15 separate text strings with which the function would use Instr to search for, it would work. That's what I meant by a particular argument taking multiple values.

Comment: You are comparing the value in a single cell with 10 or 15 text values. Don't pass the text values to the function, just the cell value. Then do the text comparison in the function. Call the function something like `IsAdminValue`. Have different functions if there are other tests. You want to avoid passing lots of parameters to a function/proc.